# Does anyone know if there is a Chrome plugin for making FireFox extensions work in Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

Does anyone know if there is a Chrome plugin for making FireFox extensions work in Chrome? Just curious because Chrome does appear to run faster, but I love my FF plugins, especially for development. I'm guessing maybe there isn't because of XUL.

Comment: At least the Greasmonkey scripts work out-of-the-box on Chrome... most of the time ;-)

Comment: @jldupont - Good to know, but this makes sense I guess since it's only JS.

Comment: It'd be nice if Chrome got a little more mind/market share and therefore more attention to plugin development. Firefox is starting to feel slow, outmoded and clunky.

Comment: your FF might be faster without all the plugins :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there isn't and there won't be. Chromium extensions have a completely different design philosophy, they are written as plain old HTML and javascript pages. They are also sandboxed and run in their own process so that an extension won't hang or crash the browser process. The extensions system is progressing rapidly and as that occurs you'll start to see some extensions that are comparable to the firefox add-ons.

See http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/overview.html for details.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of such plugin on Chrome: it would be a major undertaking probably not worth the effort in face of just porting to CHrome.

If you are talking about NPAPI plugins (sometimes people get those mixed up with extensions), then the said plugins should work on Chrome: Chrome supports NPAPI.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.firebreath.org perhaps (cross browser plugin platform)